# Sending byte strings to serial device

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I'm using Python3 running on a Raspberry. I have a serial device (max232/PiC16F84) connected to the Raspberry via an USB to Serial adapter.
I try to send two bytes to the device (e.g 0000 0011) which then will be interpreted as a command by the PIC.
The USB - serial adapter is configured correctly and the parameter such as bauderate should be ok. I guess that my code doesn't send the correct bytes to the serial port.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate=1200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    xonxoff=serial.XOFF,
    rtscts=False,
    dsrdtr=False
)

ser.open()
ser.isOpen()

print("Initializing the device ..")

ser.write(bytes(0x00))

print("Write command")
ser.write (bytes(0x04))

print('Done')
```

Comment: What symptoms lead you to believe it's not sending the correct bytes?  What are the correct bytes (where's the protocol definition)?

Answer (score 10):

You are using the `bytes` constructor incorrectly. When you call it with an `int` as argument, you get:

> bytes(int) -> bytes object of size given by the parameter initialized with null bytes

So `bytes(0x00)` (which is just `bytes(0)`) is the empty string, and `bytes(0x04)` is four zero bytes:

```
>>> bytes(0x00)
b''
>>> bytes(0x04)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

What you want is `bytes([ 0x00 ])` etc., or simply an array with all your byte values:

```
>>> bytes([0, 4])
b'\x00\x04'
```

If the string is short, you could simply write it as a constant: `b'\x00\x04'`, for example. See the documentation of `bytes()` for more options.

Answer (score -3):

Use this:
bytes[0x00]+bytes([0x04])